# "...FDA, who...." vs "...FDA, which..." - relative-pronouns of authorities

Tags: word-choice, animacy, relative-pronouns

I'm referring to the following sentence: "Observes express their concerns whether the FDA, which/who is already overrun with work..."

My question is: Are authorities in the English language treated as a thing or as a person regarding relative-pronouns?

Comment: Already a related question/ duplicate exists. Please check ELU records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you treat the organisation as an entity in itself, use *which is*. If you treat the organisation as an entity comprised of  its staff, use *who are*.

> The FDA, which is already overrun with work, ...
>   The FDA, who are already overrun with work, ...

It's very unusual (to the point of being almost always wrong) to personalise the organisation itself and use **who is*.

There may be dialectal differences in whether an organisation is treated as a singular entity or a collection of staff-members. And it may also depend on the organisation: in British English you are likely to find that the government *does*, but the police *do*.

Comment: I've never noticed the last distinction you make (but I agree). Maybe it's because *the government* is so distant and amorphous, but we see *the police* day-to-day!